# Get HTML code from dynamic page

Tags: java, html, web-crawler

I am trying to get the HTML code of the following website. 
http://fortune.com/fortune500/list/

But the problem is when we visit this website in browser, it only shows the first 20 companies and when we go to the bottom part of website it loads the next 50 companies.

How do i get the first 700 companies in HTML code from this website?
I tried the code from this website https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-url-content-in-java/ to get the HTML content but as expected it gives only the top 20 companies

Any help is much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Programmatically you won't be able to do that because Ajax calls are involved in that HTML.  The approach in that link gets the HTML as it, a text with an HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks . I can parse the HTML structure in downstream but the problem is i need to get more companies list from the fortune500list website (Not first 20 companies)

Answer (score 1):

**CURL**: http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2013055/expand/item/ranking/asc/{{start_from}}/{{num_limit}}

**Example**: http://fortune.com/api/v2/list/2013055/expand/item/ranking/asc/1/100

The site "fortune.com" return **max 100** elements form CURL.

The CURL return a **JSON**.

Comment: Thanks. Calling api returns the data but I am trying in a different approach of  parse/crawl the website and find the data in it

Comment: The site fortune.com doesn&#39;t load all the data at the beginning.. Therefore you don&#39;t recover them.. (Sorry My English)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Selenium for this. Here is a [tutorial](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/crawl-dynamic-content-with-selenium-and.html) on how to use it with StormCrawler. You could also use it directly if you wanted to.